# Importing File from Marketing Cloud Safehouse with Field Level Encryption

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-extract, field-level-encryption

We have automations that run nightly which export business-critical data extensions to our Safehouse in case Marketing Cloud takes a tumble and all our data is lost.  Some of these fields in the data extension(s) have Field Level Encryption.  Is it possible to import these directly back into Marketing Cloud, from the Safehouse without the file (data extension) ever being in the sFTP?  I assume that if this is possible, the Safehouse would not honor field-level encryption.  We attempted to run an import activity referencing the file naming pattern created in the data extract, and continue to get an error.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

We learned that this functionality is not possible according to the below SF documentation.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_encryption_data_exports.htm&type=5